# Update item count of Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-arrayadapter

i'm trying to implement search feature in my app,but i am having a problem.

For example when i search to *yellow flowers* i get 200 result found, i store 200 in **NumberWalls** variable,to ;to make adapter show only 200 item in `RecyclerView`.and everthing works fin, my problem is when i search for example *Google Picture* i get 4 result found and when i search again for *yellow flowers* i see only 4 item on `RecyclerView` instead of 200.

```
 private void setAdapterForRecyclerView(List<Wallpaper> wlls, int NumberWalls) {

        if (myAdapter == null) {
            errortv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            myAdapter = new MyAdapterSearch(wlls, getApplicationContext(), new RecyclerViewClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view, Wallpaper wallpaper) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Search.this, FullScreen.class);
                    intent.putExtra("img", wallpaper.getThumbnails());
                    intent.putExtra("tags", wallpaper.getTitle());
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view, Category categories) {

                }
            }, (NumberWalls));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        } else {
            int position = myAdapter.getItemCount();
            myAdapter.getItems().addAll(wlls);
            myAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(position, NumberWalls);
        }
        progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

in Adapter :

```
public MyAdapterSearch(List<Wallpaper> wallpapers, Context context, RecyclerViewClickListener clickListener, int numberItem) {
        this.wallpapers = wallpapers;
        this.context = context;
        this.mClickListener = clickListener;
        this.numberItem = numberItem;
    }
    .
    .
    .

@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return Math.min(wallpapers.size(), numberItem);
    }
```

here's the `AsyncTask` class where i get **NumberWalls** :

```
public class fetchDataSearch extends AsyncTask<Integer, List<Wallpaper>, List<Wallpaper>> {
        Document doc = null;
        ArrayList<Wallpaper> urlsSearch = new ArrayList<>();
        String numberOnly;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected List<Wallpaper> doInBackground(Integer... integers) {
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect(getResources().getString(R.string.SearchRequest) + mSearchText.replace(" ", "+") + "&page=" + integers[0]).get();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (doc != null) {
                Element noResultfound = doc.getElementsByClass("notice notice-error").first();
                if (noResultfound != null) {
                    noResultsFoundCatched = true;
                } else {
                    Element element = doc.select("div.center > h1").first();
                    numberOnly = element.text().replaceFirst(".*?(\\d+).*", "$1");
                    Elements newsHeadlines = doc.getElementsByClass("img-responsive");
                    for (Element headline : newsHeadlines) {
                        String thumb = headline.select("img").attr("src");
                        String title = headline.select("img").attr("title");
                        Wallpaper wallpaperInfo = new Wallpaper();
                        wallpaperInfo.setThumbnails(thumb);
                        wallpaperInfo.setTitle(title);
                        if (BooleanChecker.checkTagsContains(title)) {
                            urlsSearch.add(wallpaperInfo);
                        } else {
                            unWantedTagsFound++;
                        }
                    }
                    noResultsFoundCatched = false;
                }

            } else {
                noResultsFoundCatched = true;
            }
            return urlsSearch;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Wallpaper> wallpapersSearch) {
            super.onPostExecute(wallpapersSearch);
            if (numberOnly != null) {
                numberWallpapersPage = Integer.parseInt(numberOnly);
                setAdapterForRecyclerView(wallpapersSearch, numberWallpapers);
            } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: is this the complete code?

Comment: @JawadMalik chekc my new update post

Answer (score 3):

I think you can drop the `numberItem` thing and let `getItemCount()` simply return `wallpapers.size()`. Because, you're giving the adapter the list of wallpapers that the search returns, and so I guess you want to show all of them in the list.

Also, when updating the adapter, instead of adding the search results to the list of items, simply set the results as the items.

```
myAdapter.setWallpapers(wlls);
```

and add method `setWallpapers()` to the adapter:

```
public void setWallpapers(List<Wallpaper> wallpapers) {
    this.wallpapers = wallpapers;
    notifyDatasetChanged();
}
```

Comment: See my extended answer

Comment: Thank you for your answer,it works only if i don't have lots of items ,when i scroll i lose previous items , because i show items by page every time i scroll , and this is another issue i think.

Comment: I'd say pagination is a separate topic, so you should better create a new question for it, and accept my answer for fixing the itemcount problem.